# How do I enable row selection in an ASP GridView without disabling EnableEventValidation?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASPX page that includes a GridView. I want to be able to select a row from the grid, and populate another section of the page based on the selected row. It works if I have EnableEventValidation="false" in the <%@ Page %> line, but I have been told that I cannot use that because of a security concern. When I don't include it, selecting a grid row throws an "Invalid postback or callback argument" exception.

How can I implement row selection without disabling event validation?

Here is my code:

ASPX page:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="TheGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="id" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" AllowSorting="true">
    <Columns>                               
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Email" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

ASPX.VB code:

```
Protected Sub TheGrid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles TheGrid.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(TheGrid, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.Attributes("style") = "cursor:pointer"
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("TheGrid")
    MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub
```

Note that when I select a row, the exception is thrown somewhere between Page_Load and Render.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets wire up the GV two ways.

First way, drop in a plane jane button for the row click
(we will delete the button and add row click in 2nd example).

so, say this simple GV

```
<div id="MyGridArea" runat="server" clientidmode="static">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID"
        CssClass="table table-hover" Width="60em" GridLines="None"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn myshadow"
                        OnClick="cmdEdit_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Note how we just dropped in a plane jane button.

And our code to fill out above is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()
    Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    GridView1.DataSource = Myrst(strSQL)
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And now we have this:

[image]

Ok, so next part is to drop in a "div" area that allows edit of one row.

So, again, quite much plan jane controls.

And we can "hide" grid when we edit, and show edit area div.

But, I often use jQuery.UI. Really amounts to much the same code as simple hide/show, but this way jQuery.UI turns that SAME div into a nice pop up area.

So, that div area might look like this:

```
        <div id="EditRecord" runat="server" style="float: left; display: none" clientidmode="Static">

            <br />
            <div style="float: left" class="iForm">

                <label>HotelName</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" f="HotelName" Width="280">
                </asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <label>First Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" f="FirstName" Width="140"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" f="LastName" Width="140"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />

                <label>City</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server" f="City" Width="140"></asp:TextBox>

                <br />
                <label>Province</label><asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" f="Province" Width="75"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
```

etc. etc. etc.

so, now lets wire up the button above.

The button will simple:

Get current grid row

Get PK id

Load up div and display.

So, that code is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    EditRow(gRow.RowIndex)

End Sub

Sub EditRow(rowNum As Integer)

    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(rowNum).Item("ID")
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = " & intPK

    Dim rstData As DataTable = Myrst(strSQL)

    ' load up our edit div
    fLoader(Me.EditRecord, rstData.Rows(0))
    ViewState("PK") = intPK

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Page.GetType, "mypopedit", "popedit()", True)

End Sub
```

As noted, I added a popup from jQuery.UI, but we could just use plain jane "div" and hide/show the grid and show the edit area (or like you have, have that edit area in full view).

(fLoader is a routine I built some time ago - I like everyone became VERY tired of typing code over and over to fill out text boxes etc., so for any text box etc., I use a "made up" attribute called f="Data base column name", and that routine just loops the controls on the form and fills them out. No different than hand coding simple assignments to controls, but with this code I can re-use it over and over.

So, we now see, get this:

[image]

Ok, so the only next goal is to add a row click
(and not use that edit button).

So, then all we need is a routine that will get the current row index, and call our edit row routine we have above.

So, we use row data bound, and add that click event that way.

but, do note how the above button click gets the current row. That nice short code works for repeaters, listview etc. (we used naming container).

But, if you want a row click in place of that button?

Then on row data bound, add this code:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick",
             "__doPostBack('myrowedit'," & e.Row.RowIndex & ")")

    End If

End Sub
```

And in our page load event, we have this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    Else
        If Request("__EVENTTARGET") = "myrowedit" Then
            EditRow(Request("__EVENTARGUMENT"))
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

And a handy dandy routine that returns a table based on SQL I used above was this:

```
Public Function Myrst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, mycon)
            mycon.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using

    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

So, all in all, not a lot of code.

You can try the above working example here:

http://www.kallal.ca/Website11/WebForm2